# How can I run KafkaStream application with Micronaut?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, micronaut

From https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-kafka/latest/guide/#kafkaStream, I can see there is an easy way of running an app which runs KStream.

If I don't want to use KStream, but want to use KafkaStream API with topology pattern, is this something achievable with Micronaut?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. As @groo points out, Kafka Streams is a library. You do build a topology, a `KStream` is a node in that topology.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you sure can. Kafka streams is a client library that you add as a dependency and package together with your application. It does not depend on how you deploy it, you should consider number of instances / threads thought as it's directed related to how the load is shared between your application instances.

And just for clarify the confusion Kafka Streams is the Library name and KStream is the type that you can use in your application, please check the below links for clarification.

https://kafka.apache.org/22/documentation/streams/core-concepts

https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/javadocs/index.html?org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/package-summary.html